# Filter in Yii is not returning

Tags: yii, yii-filters

I am trying to user filters in YII.
here is my code.

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
            'provideronly +uploadclients,fileview,editprofile,getinvitedusers',

    );
}
   public function filterProvideronly($filterchain)
   {
    if(Yii::app()->user->providerId==-1)
    {
        $this->redirect(array('site/error','id'=>403,'message'=>'You are unauthorized to view this page'));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

When the user is unauthorized to use the controller it is redirecting to error page. but when the user is authorized , it is showing a blank page..

what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: Seems you already figured out that you have to call `$filterChain->run()`. Take a look at the manual [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return true you need to put $filterChain->run(); so yii can see that the filter ended.